# onEdit(e) not triggering createFolder + enable trigger for new rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

Seems like onEdit(e) won't trigger creating a new folder in google drive - only works when running it explicitly. Any ideas? Thanks

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var requestRow = e.range.getRow();
  var folderName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(requestRow,6).getValue();
  var newFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1LOfkVGrV-juzUiwbU8owHj74T9wMAz').createFolder(folderName);
}
```

Comment: Simple `onEdit(e)` triggers do not have authorisation to call `DriveApp`, you need to set this up as an installable trigger instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [createFile() in google Apps Script is not functioning properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26661545/createfile-in-google-apps-script-is-not-functioning-properly)

Comment: Like Ross mentioned, you should use installable triggers instead, [here is instructions for it](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function func1(e) {
  DriveApp.getFolderById('1LOfkVGrV-juzUiwbU8owHj74T9wMAz').createFolder(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,6).getValue());
}

function isTrigger(funcName){
  var r=false;
  if(funcName){
    var allTriggers=ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
    for(var i=0;i<allTriggers.length;i++){
      if(funcName==allTriggers[i].getHandlerFunction()){
        r=true;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return r;
}
```

Run this once to create the trigger.

```
function createOnEditTrigger() {
  if(!isTrigger('func1')){
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('func1').forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId()).onEdit().create();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Cooper, any idea how to make it work for new rows only?

Comment: Check the [event objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) to see if you meet any of the requirements.

Comment: Yes that's great, "onChange(e)" with e.changeType == 'INSERT_ROW' should do it, but not sure how to make it run. Added it as below, but doesn't work -

`function func1(e) {
  if (e.changeType == 'INSERT_ROW') {
DriveApp.getFolderById('1LOfkVGrV-juzUiwbU8owHj74T9wMAz').createFolder(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,6).getValue());
}}`